# Error Upload Image to Server

Tags: android, upload

I have EditProfilAcitivity if i click imageview will select from gallery and no have problem. I have problem id i click button upload.

```
    package net.drieanto.lagidimana;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import net.drieanto.lagidimana.library.AlertDialogManager;
import net.drieanto.lagidimana.library.ConnectionDetector;
import net.drieanto.lagidimana.library.UserFunctions;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.provider.MediaStore.MediaColumns;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class EditProfileActivity extends Activity {
    UserFunctions userFunctions;
    Button btnLogout, buttonsearch;
    EditText editSearch;

    private ListView list;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private RibbonMenuView rbmView;
    private Button test;
    private ListView rbmListView;
    private ListView rbmListView2;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapt;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2;

    ListView list1;
    LazyAdapter adapter1;
    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
    // Alert dialog manager
    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();
    // Connection detector
    ConnectionDetector cd;
    String selectedPath = "";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /**
         * Dashboard Screen for the application
         * */
        // Check login status in database
        userFunctions = new UserFunctions();
        if (userFunctions.isUserLoggedIn(getApplicationContext())) {
            setContentView(R.layout.editprofile);
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11){
                ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
                bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.rgb(254,194,12)));
                int actionBarTitleId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
                TextView actionBarTextView = (TextView)findViewById(actionBarTitleId);
                actionBarTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            }
            // Check if Internet present
            cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
            if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
                // Internet Connection is not present
                alert.showAlertDialog(EditProfileActivity.this,
                        "Internet Connection Error",
                        "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
                // stop executing code by return
                return;
            }
            /** Menu **/
            rbmView = (RibbonMenuView) findViewById(R.id.ribbonMenuView1);
            list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

            ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(
                    EditProfileActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            EditProfileTask EditProfileTask = new EditProfileTask(
                    EditProfileActivity.this, progressDialog);
            EditProfileTask.execute();

            ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.gambarAvatar);
            image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent i = new Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                    startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
                }
            });

            editSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);
            buttonsearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonsearch);
            buttonsearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent search = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            SearchActivity.class);
                    search.putExtra("data", editSearch.getText().toString());
                    search.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(search);
                    finish();
                }
            });

            /**
             * This is an exmaple button it calls "hideMenu()" after each click
             * similiar to the Facebook or Google+ apps
             * **/

            btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogout);
            btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    userFunctions.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                    Intent login = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            LoginActivity.class);
                    login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(login);
                    // Closing dashboard screen
                    finish();
                }
            });

            /**
             * This is the most important ListView, updating the main list in
             * the Activity
             **/
            final String[] items_list = { "Home", "Follower", "Request", "View Profile" };
            adapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(EditProfileActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items_list);
            rbmListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.rbm_listview);
            rbmListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                DashboardActivity.class);
                        dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(dashboard);
                        finish();
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        Intent follower = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                FollowerActivity.class);
                        follower.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(follower);
                        finish();
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        Intent request = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                RequestActivity.class);
                        request.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(request);
                        finish();
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        Intent profil = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                ProfilActivity.class);
                        profil.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(profil);
                        // Closing dashboard screen
                        finish();
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                    }
                    rbmView.hideMenu();
                }
            });
            rbmListView.setAdapter(adapt);

        } else {
            // user is not logged in show login screen
            Intent login = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    LoginActivity.class);
            login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(login);
            // Closing dashboard screen
            finish();
        }
        Button upload = (Button)findViewById(R.id.imguploadbtn);
        upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new ImageUpload().execute();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaColumns.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            selectedPath = getPath(selectedImage);
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            final String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.gambarAvatar);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
        }

    }

    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }

    /*private void doFileUpload(){
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        DataInputStream inStream = null;
        String lineEnd = "rn";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary =  "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;
        String responseFromServer = "";
        String urlString = "http://git.drieanto.net/upload/upload.php";
        try
        {
         //------------------ CLIENT REQUEST
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(selectedPath) );
         // open a URL connection to the Servlet
         URL url = new URL(urlString);
         // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
         conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
         // Allow Inputs
         conn.setDoInput(true);
         // Allow Outputs
         conn.setDoOutput(true);
         // Don't use a cached copy.
         conn.setUseCaches(false);
         // Use a post method.
         conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
         conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
         conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);
         dos = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream() );
         dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
         dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + selectedPath + "\"" + lineEnd);
         dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
         // create a buffer of maximum size
         bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
         bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
         buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
         // read file and write it into form...
         bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
         while (bytesRead > 0)
         {
          dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
          bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
          bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
          bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
         }
         // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
         dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
         dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
         // close streams
         Log.e("Debug","File is written");
         fileInputStream.close();
         dos.flush();
         dos.close();
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException ex)
        {
             Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
             Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
        }
        //------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE
        try {
              inStream = new DataInputStream ( conn.getInputStream() );
              String str;

              while (( str = inStream.readLine()) != null)
              {
                   Log.e("Debug","Server Response "+str);
              }
              inStream.close();

        }
        catch (IOException ioex){
             Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
        }
      }*/

    /**
     * Allows users, even API < 5, to use the back button
     * 
     * public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { switch (keyCode)
     * { case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK: rbmView.hideMenu(); break; default: return
     * super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); } return true; }
     */
    /**
     * Options Menu<br>
     * example toggle
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.test:
            rbmView.toggleMenu();
            break;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void showEditError(int responseCode) {
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Terjadi Error", duration);
        toast.show();
    }

    public void showEditSuccess(int responseCode) {
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Terjadi Error", duration);
        toast.show();
    }

    class ImageUpload extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... unsued) {

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            DataOutputStream dos = null;
            DataInputStream inStream = null;
            String lineEnd = "rn";
            String twoHyphens = "--";
            String boundary =  "*****";
            int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
            byte[] buffer;
            int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;
            String responseFromServer = "";
            String urlString = "http://lagidimana.net/upload/upload.php";
            try
            {
             //------------------ CLIENT REQUEST
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(selectedPath) );
             // open a URL connection to the Servlet
             URL url = new URL(urlString);
             // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
             conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
             // Allow Inputs
             conn.setDoInput(true);
             // Allow Outputs
             conn.setDoOutput(true);
             // Don't use a cached copy.
             conn.setUseCaches(false);
             // Use a post method.
             conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
             conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
             conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);
             dos = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream() );
             dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
             dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + selectedPath + "\"" + lineEnd);
             dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
             // create a buffer of maximum size
             bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
             bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
             buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
             // read file and write it into form...
             bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
             while (bytesRead > 0)
             {
              dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
              bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
              bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
              bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
             }
             // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
             dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
             dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
             // close streams
             Log.e("Debug","File is written");
             fileInputStream.close();
             dos.flush();
             dos.close();
            }
            catch (MalformedURLException ex)
            {
                 Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
            }
            catch (IOException ioe)
            {
                 Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
            }
            //------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE
            try {
                  inStream = new DataInputStream ( conn.getInputStream() );
                  String str;

                  while (( str = inStream.readLine()) != null)
                  {
                       Log.e("Debug","Server Response "+str);
                  }
                  inStream.close();

            }
            catch (IOException ioex){
                 Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

upload.php file

```
<?php
// Where the file is going to be placed
$target_path = "uploads/";

/* Add the original filename to our target path.
Result is "uploads/filename.extension" */
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']).
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    echo "filename: " .  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
    echo "target_path: " .$target_path;
}
?>
```

i have chmod 777 folder uploads/

Error Message in logcat in bottom, but i don't understand with this error. Maybe you have same problem.

```
06-14 21:46:35.339: E/Debug(13682): File is written
06-14 21:46:53.339: E/Debug(13682): Server Response There was an error uploading the file, please try again!filename: target_path: uploads/
```

please help thank's

Comment: Can you post ALL of the logcat error please? Looks like there is some missing...

Comment: it all logcat message with red error, but in editprofilactivity not full script

Comment: OK. Can't say I didn't try!

Comment: i have edit with full code please help

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function doFileUpload from the Main UI thread. Android does not allow you to make Network calls on the main thread.

Build an Asynctask and do the upload process of connecting to the network from another thread (in the doInBackground function).